# How can I profile popup-open in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, profiling

I have a Chrome Extension. On first launch it can be a little slow so I want to know why, but I can't figure out how to profile extensions.

Once the popup is open it's easy to use the profiler in the dev tools, but if you start recording then close the popup, the session is ended

How can I profile the actual opening of the extension?

The extension works on Firefox as well, so if there is a workaround to do the profiling in Firefox it's ok, but I'd rather do it with Chrome's better tools

Comment: Should be as simple as pressing the reload icon in the devtools profiler https://puu.sh/EfbJC/096d6dba84.png

Comment: Ah that works! How about for very first launch, is there a trick for being able to profile that? First launch is the slowest and I basically cannot access the dev tools until its complete

Comment: You can start the profiler in the background page and it'll record the opening of the popup. Alternatively, you can open a new empty tab, open devtools profiler, start it, then copypaste the popup's full URL in the address bar. Also, there's chrome://tracing for some [really obscure stuff](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool).